# Добавить значения в хеш

Tags: ruby

Подскажите, как сформировать подобный хеш. У меня есть цикл вида:

```
sms_send = {}
SmsSend.all.each do |record|
    if !record.is_send
      sms_send.merge!(record.sms_number => Russian.translit(record.sms_text))
      record.is_send = 1
      record.save
    end
```

На выходе сейчас хеш выглядит так: 
`{'12345678' => 'test1', '123456789' => 'test1'}`, 
а как сделать так, чтобы туда добавлялся еще одно значение, `record.uid`, чтобы на выходе был такой хеш:

```
{
  'record.uid(1)' =>
    {
      record.sms_number(1) => Russian.translit(record.sms_text(1))
    },
  'record.uid(2)' =>
    {
      record.sms_number(2) => Russian.translit(record.sms_text(2))
    }
}
```

т.е., чтобы сначала был уникальный ключ `record.uid`, а потом шли значения? Чтобы на каждой итерации туда добавлялись значения, в зависимости от условия.

Answer (score 1):

Если `uid` уникален, то можно использовать такую конструкцию:

```
sms_end = {}
SmsSend.find_each.with_object(sms_end) do |record, memo|
  next if record.is_send
  memo[record.uid] = {record.sms_number => Russian.translit(record.sms_text)}
end
```

В результат сохранится в `sms_end`.

Как подсказали в комментариях, это наиболее оптимальный вариант.

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, чем стала хуже читаемость? :) Тем, что используется переменная чуть дальше, чем из текущей области видимости, что ранее было покрыто `each_with_object`? Так можно ж сделать `.find_each.with_object(sms_send)`.

Comment: @D-side, ну я не уверен что прям хуже стало. Просто стараюсь в блоках избегать, где можно, переменные из-вне. Про `with_object`, к своему стыду, не знал. Так и правда получается аккуратнее. Спасибо. Единственный минус - методы чейнятся. Но, в любом случае, это, как минимум, не хуже, чем первый вариант.